# Can salt water kill bacteria in septic tank

Tags: septic

My septic tank has open bottom and as it's rainy season and the salt water from the ground (clay) is coming up to a foot, but I'm wondering whether it can kill all the bacteria (anaerobic, aerobic) which eats away the sludge?

Also I'm wondering if there are any recommended liquids or something which increases biological activity in the septic tank. (I'm finding some septic tank cleaners but there are both equal and negative reviews.)

The toilet cleaners like Harpic etc, does have to power to kill off bacteria's in septic tank.

What about hot waters impact on the biological system inside the septic tank?

It'd be good to have some insights into this.

Comment: I don't think any chemicals should be added to the septic system, as it eventually gets into the groundwater, which often is the source of your drinking water. Instead, you shall follow the good practices of septic system construction. Here is a good reference, https://www.epa.gov/septic/types-septic-systems

Comment: The link that you have shared is quite useful. I'm grateful for it. Thanks

Comment: add sugar if you want more microbes. it does wonders for composting, giving it a jump start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, many things that end up in a septic tank can harm the bacteria that break down wastes.  You've named a few such as salt water and cleaning products.  Also things like medications that you take, especially antibiotics can affect the bacteria.

Generally septic tanks rely on the sheer volume of the tank contents vs. the influx of harmful agents but at times the incoming can overwhelm the tank.  Over time the bacteria should recover but there are any number of commercial products that claim to replenish the helpful flora. You can find these are hardware stores as well as from septic tank service companies.

Comment: Pro-biotics are also a thing, they are sold OTC as a digestive aid.

Comment: Thanks , probably try some pro-biotics